# What exactly does "Can't send long data for non-string/non-binary data types" mean?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, blob

I am attempting to INSERT a single file's data into a LONGBLOB column via PHP along with some other data like the file's name, size in bytes, sha256 checksum, etc.

I know there is nothing wrong with the table itself, as I am able to INSERT the file and the rest of the columns all at once through phpMyAdmin which suggests that I use the following MySQL INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME (SHA256SUM, FILE_NAME, FILE_DATA) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

So my PHP code currently looks like this:

```
$mysqli_query = 'INSERT INTO DB_NAME.TABLE_NAME (SHA256SUM, FILE_NAME, FILE_DATA) VALUES (?, ?, ?)';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($mysqli_query);
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("ssb", $sha256sum, $_FILES['career_application_FILE_UPLOAD']['name'], $null);
$stmt->send_long_data(0, file_get_contents($_FILES['career_application_FILE_UPLOAD']['tmp_name']));
$stmt->execute();
```

Which is pretty much exactly what Oracle suggests [right here](https://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_s_mysqli_extension_storing).

But for some reason it just hasn't been working for me. (And trust me, I have been trying for the past 3 hours.)

It kept returning the general MySQL error "COLUMN FILE_DATA CANNOT BE NULL".

So I enabled NULL values on the FILE_DATA column, and then the INSERT would work, but the FILE_DATA column (which is supposed to be filled with BLOB data) just reads NULL.

So I disabled NULL values on the FILE_DATA column and I placed a `$stmt_error = $stmt->error;` line just after the send_long_data section and I caught the following error:

> Can't send long data for non-string/non-binary data types

I tried deciphering what that meant, and was unable to, so here I am asking for help.

I'm going to get some sleep, and hopefully in the morning I can answer my own silly question... I just have this feeling that it's something so entirely obvious I am too tired to notice it right now.

Some details:

- I am running this code on Debian 8 and NGINX v1.6.2
- I have quadruple-checked that my MySQL max_allowed_packet is set to the default 16776192 (which shouldn't matter anyways, as the files I am attempting to upload are a few bytes to a few kilobytes in size)
- I have attempted uploading all different types of files (txt, mov, png, pdf, etc)
- I am not unfamiliar with PHP or MySQL at all, I have been working with them both for over 10 years now
- I even tried setting the LONGBLOB collation to binary, since the entire table's collation was ascii... but it wasn't possible to change the LONGBLOB collation, nor should it matter since like I said originally... phpMyAdmin has no problem inserting file data into the LONGBLOB column)

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please add the actual table structure what is related to your error AND sql statement and the related error message and error code. Also I noticed  `$stmt->send_long_data(0,` first parameter, should it be 2 no?!

Comment: @BalazsVago thank you so much. I misinterpreted what the first parameter of send_long_data actually was. That solved it! switching the 0, for a 2, since it was the 3rd parameter... smh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my stupidity, I failed to read the spec for send_long_data in it's entirety and just assumed that 0 was an insignificant placeholder for something.

It's not insignificant.

It was meant to be 2. To equate to the 3rd parameter of the MySQL INSERT.